# OleControl Events in a C# Forms ActiveX control

Tags: c#, forms, activex, ole

I have an Windows.Forms.UserControl as an ActiveX Control. It is used in a SAPGUI and work well. With the new version 7.6 of the SAPGUI (Win32), I get some issues and the hint of SAP development was, I should wait for the COleControl::OnFreezeEvents are false, to do my actions.
My question is now, how can I get this OleControl to overwrite this method or can I attach to the IOleControl::FreezeEvents?